# A couple of questions about tenses

Tags: grammar

> They were supposed to have been gone.
>
> We were supposed to have been contemplated about this matter before.

Are these tenses correct? If so, what do they mean?

Comment: Thise are not tenses! The only tense there is past tense because you said *were* not *are* in the present tense. Those are the only two tenses English has: past and present. Aspect&voice aren't tenses. All the other verbs are nonfinite, which means they cannot have tense by pure definition. The verb constructions you are attempting to use are awfully hard to make sense of, and I'm nearly positive the second is not grammatical. I'm sending this to our sister site for English Language Learners, where you may be able to get help that uses the words you seem to be expecting to hear here.

Comment: Actually, "have been gone" and "have been consulted" are perfect tense, which is a secondary past tense.

Comment: Your sentences look like the passive to me, which they don't need to be. _They were supposed to have gone_ and _We were supposed to have contemplated this matter before_ would be more natural.

Comment: The first is not passive. "Gone" is an adjective here, not a verb.